# Autoloading Zend Framework 2 packages with the StandardAutoloader

Tags: zend-framework2

I was previously using a downloaded version of Zend Framework 2 and was basically able to do something like this:

```
// Set include paths (add Zend to the path)
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $__CONFIG['zendPath']);

// Setup the Zend Autoloader
require_once('library\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php');

$autoLoader = new StandardAutoloader(array(
    'namespaces' => array(
        'Zend' => $__CONFIG['zendPath'] . '/library/Zend'
    )
));
```

This works because all Zend packages are inside the library folder. I now wanted to use composer to load only the Zend packages I need. The problem I'm running into is that the packages get arranged in the following way:

```
zendframework/zend-cache/Zend/...
zendframework/zend-loader/Zend/...
zendframework/zend-validator/Zend/...
etc.
```

I tried having separate namespace declarations in the StandardAutoloader like this:

```
$autoLoader = new StandardAutoloader(array(
    'namespaces' => array(
        'Zend\Cache' => $__CONFIG['zendPath'] . '/library/zend-cache/Zend/Cache',
        'Zend\Loader' => $__CONFIG['zendPath'] . '/library/zend-loader/Zend/Loader',
        'Zend\Validator' => $__CONFIG['zendPath'] . '/library/zend-validator/Zend/Validator'
    )
));
```

That doesn't work. Am assuming the namespace probably can't have the backslashes in it? is there any way to make this work? Preferably without having to define each individual package.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to fix the paths:

```
$libs = $__CONFIG['zendPath'];
$autoLoader = new StandardAutoloader(array(
    'namespaces' => array(
        'Zend\Cache' => $libs . '/library/zend-cache/Zend',
        'Zend\Loader' => $libs . '/library/zend-loader/Zend',
        'Zend\Validator' => $libs . '/library/zend-validator/Zend',
    )
));
```

That should do the trick (it's un-tested, so I'm not sure about the trailing `Zend`

Answer (score 0):

Let it autoload Zend for you:

```
$autoLoader = new StandardAutoloader(array(
    'autoregister_zf' => true, // Auto load Zend Namespace..
    'namespaces' => array(
         // extra namespaces
    )
));
```

Comment: That doesn't work when packages are manually included like that

Comment: you sure? It just registered the Zend namespace.. it's the exact same structure it shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: no, that particular flag assumes the library is in a single location: see https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php#L89-L93

Comment: ahh my bad I never realised they were in different folders I never looked properly, I assumed they would all be inside a Zend folder which would be fine

Comment: don't see why they all can't be stuck in a Zend folder though... :)

Comment: different git submodules... Also not sure why he has such a setup, but I am a composer user, so I simply don't bother understanding what I got away from :P

Comment: yeah I had assumed it would all be in a single Zend folder as there's no reason why not to and it would make this method work for him