# Zend Framework GData Youtube Loading issue

Tags: youtube-api, zend-framework2, gdata

I am trying to use Gdata package of Zend-2 framework to access Youtube API.

I have a successfully working version with Zend 1.9 version. I am trying to port them to Zend 2 framework version.

The folder structure is

C:\wamp\www\plugins\youtube\
C:\wamp\www\plugins\youtube\Zend\ (all default folders that comes with ZF2)
C:\wamp\www\plugins\youtube\Zend\ZendGData (downloaded separately from Zend Packages page)

I have added the path C:\wamp\www\plugins\youtube\ to the include_path by using set_include_path() function and have verified the same.

I am using the below code to create the YouTube object.

```
$yt = new ZendGData\YouTube();
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Class 'ZendGData\YouTube' not found
```

I am not how to use the auto-loading feature of ZF2. I tried to include the Loader/StandardAutoloader.php file. But still the same.

If I include the Zend\ZendGData\YouTube.php file I get the notice that the ZendGData\Media is not found.

Please let me know if I am missing something silly.

**EDIT:**

Some more information on what I have done now.
Based on search from Stackoverflow site, I did the below changes.

```
use Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader;  
use ZendGdata\YouTube;

require_once 'C:\wamp\www\plugins\youtube\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();

$yt = new Zend\ZendGData\YouTube();
```

Now I get the below error.

```
Class 'ZendGData\Media' not found
```

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated.. if any info is missing on this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error with the AutoLoader, the below code worked for me. If someone is having the same issue, here is the solution.

```
    require_once 'C:\wamp\www\youtube\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php';

    $loader = new StandardAutoloader(array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'namespaces' => array(
                  'ZendGData' => 'C:\wamp\www\youtube\Zend\ZendGdata\')
                    )
    );

    $loader->register();

    $yt = new ZendGData\YouTube();
```

Comment: I modified and got the above solution found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162157/autoloading-zend-framework-2-packages-with-the-standardautoloader?rq=1

Comment: try not to use absolute paths because if you have to move your project to linux then that just creates alot of extra work for you. I've always hated seeing hard coded paths in code, most annoying ever.

Comment: Yeah. I got your point. I have use the code in a different manner. The code sample provided here is an example to make it simple